# How do I send all the rows in the table?

Tags: php, html

You are going to send the full line value using form tag. However, if you send a value, only the value in the last row is sent. How should it be modified?

in this table code

```
 echo "<form action='../verification/medical_bills_check.php' method='post'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      
 
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='id' value ='" . $row['id'] . " '>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";   
        echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='storename' value ='" . $row['storename'] . " '>" . $row['storename'] . "</td>";    
        echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='corporate_num' value ='" . $row['corporate_num'] . " '>" . $row['corporate_num'] . "</td>";  
        echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='store_mbrno' value ='" . $row['store_mbrno'] . " '>" . $row['store_mbrno'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='store_mbrno_van' value ='" . $row['store_mbrno_van'] . " '>" . $row['store_mbrno_van'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td ><input type='hidden' name='past_cash_receipts' value ='" . $row['past_cash_receipts'] . " '>" . $row['past_cash_receipts'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='past_card' value ='" . $row['past_card'] . " '>" . $row['past_card'] . "</td>";                                        
        echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='pg_select' value ='" . $row['pg_select'] . " '>" . $row['pg_select'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='program_select' value ='" . $row['program_select'] . " '>" . $row['program_select'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='authority' value ='" . $row['authority'] . " '>" . $row['authority'] . "</td>";   
        echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='apikey' value ='" . $row['apikey'] . " '>" . $row['apikey'] . "</td>";   
    
        echo "<td > <input type='submit'> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      
    }
 echo "</form>";
```

and receive page code

```
   $_SESSION["corporate_num"] = $_POST["corporate_num"];
    $_SESSION["store_mbrno"]  = $_POST["store_mbrno"];
    $_SESSION["store_mbrno_van"] = $_POST["store_mbrno_van"];
    $_SESSION["program_select"] = $_POST["program_select"];
    $_SESSION["authority"] = $_POST["authority"];
    $_SESSION["apikey"] =$_POST["apikey"];
```

I want result

```
id        |    corporate_num   |   store_mbrno |          submit
1                  1                    1               submit_button
2                  2                    2               submit_button
3                  3                    3               submit_button
4                  4                    4               submit_button
```

When I submit id 1 rows.
Received Page receive value id:1 / corporate_num:1/ store_mbrno:1

When I submit id 2 rows.
Received Page receive value id:2 / corporate_num:2/ store_mbrno:2

Comment: Just to clarify: you have a table with many rows, with each row having some data and a submit button. You want the submit button to only POST the data of that row, but instead you get the data of the last row in the table, is that correct?

Comment: Do you want to send the value of just the specific row? In that case you need one `<form>` per row.

Comment: Or, if you want to send all the rows to the server at once, then all your `name` values need `[]` at the end, so they can contain lists. e.g. `name='id[]'`, `name='storename[]'` etc.

Comment: @DaanWilmer I would like to send the value of the row in a single submit.

Comment: @ADyson I want to transfer all the selected rows values.

Comment: when you say "selected" rows, do you mean the user can select one or more particular rows to submit? How is that being done?

Comment: @ADyson modify it

Comment: ok so it sounds like you just want to send one row at a time (but send all values within that row). In that case you need one `<form>` per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the issue is that you have a lot of `input` fields with the same `name` within one `form`. What happens when you click one of the buttons, is that all the data in the whole `form` gets sent. And, because every row has fields with the same `name`, the values get overwritten by the next row. Therefore only the data of the last row is sent.

If you only want to send the data of one row, you need to have the data in a separate `form`. So, one `form` for each row. Since, technically, you can't have a `form` element directly inside a `table` or `tr` element, I suggest putting the `form` element and all hidden `input`s in the last table cell.

Furthermore, since the contents of the hidden `input`s can be modified (you can't trust your visitors not to use the inspector), you should not trust the information that is sent. Instead, if possible, only send the id, and fetch the other information anew from the database.